# Hide image popup

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Need a little help. I'm tryng to display a pop up only after i close the popup the image apears in place of the div how can i hide it after i close the popup?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"70%" , height:"100%"});
    $("#inline_content").css({inline:true, width:"70%" , height:"100%", display:"block"});
});
```

This is the div i'm using to display the images

```
<div id='inline_content' style=' width:100%; height:100%; display:none;' ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

there is an option available as part of colorbox called onClosed that fires when its closed try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#inline_content").css({inline:true, width:"70%" , height:"100%", display:"block"});
   $(".inline").colorbox({
       height:"100%",
       width:"70%",
       onClosed: function () {
          $("#inline_content").hide();
       }
});
});
```

all in all though your question is pretty confusing I am pretty sure this is what you were looking for

Comment: Soory for late answer smt like that but this is stopping the popup to display

Comment: even worse :D still loads the image after i close the popup and instead of img in popup i ghet the entire page :))

Comment: hmmm do you have a link to the page? or can you better explain what you are trying to do? I am having a hard time visioning it >.>, 

if you are trying to open that image only when the page is loaded and have it not appear again there is an option to pass colorbox html, like so: $.colorbox({html:"<div style='width:701px;height:400px'><img src='yourimage.jpg' /></div>"}); If not you may need to go into more detail, or provide a link

Comment: loong stoory short. I have all images in db, i extract thumbs of images parse the id trouth ajax and return from that id the big img wich i display in popup.